# Python to keep top 10 rows of Excel file

Tags: python, excel

Windows 7 + Python 2.76

An Excel file of structure 20 rows and 6 columns.

I want to have new file keeping on the top 10 rows (of their correspondent 6 columns as well) only.

Is this a good way?

```
old_file = open_workbook(“c:\\the_file.xls”,formatting_info=True)
old_sheet = old_file.sheet_by_index(0)

new_file = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8', style_compression = 0)
new_sheet = new_file.add_sheet('Sheet1', cell_overwrite_ok = True)

columns0 = []
columns1 = []
columns2 = []
columns3 = []
columns4 = []
columns5 = []

for row in range(10):

    column_0 = old_sheet.cell(row,0).value
    column_1 = old_sheet.cell(row,1).value
    column_2 = old_sheet.cell(row,2).value
    column_3 = old_sheet.cell(row,3).value
    column_4 = old_sheet.cell(row,4).value
    column_5 = old_sheet.cell(row,5).value

columns0.append(column_0)
columns1.append(column_1)
columns2.append(column_2)
columns3.append(column_3)
columns4.append(column_4)
columns5.append(column_5)

for b0, content0 in enumerate(columns0):
    new_sheet.write(b0, 0, content0)

for b1, content1 in enumerate(columns1):
    new_sheet.write(b1, 1, content1)

for b2, content2 in enumerate(columns2):
    new_sheet.write(b2, 2, content2)

for b3, content3 in enumerate(columns3):
    new_sheet.write(b3, 3, content3)

for b4, content4 in enumerate(columns4):
    new_sheet.write(b4, 4, content4)

for b5, content5 in enumerate(columns5):
    new_sheet.write(b5, 5, content5)

new_file.save("C:\\new_file.xls")
```

It works but the codes don’t look neat.

What would be a better way?

Comment: This question might be better on codereview.stackexchange.com , a Q&A site for improving code clarity and style.

Comment: @jwg, thanks for the guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or much more simpler with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
orig_df = pd.read_excel(orig_excel_path, sheetname=sheetname)
orig_df.head(10).to_excel(new_excel_path, sheet_name=new_sheetname)
```

Comment: thanks! would pandas be helpful to another question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042404/python-to-save-needed-rows-in-excel-contents

Comment: Yes it will, I answered there.

Answer (score 1):

No, its not a good way, this is a usecase for loops, Example -

```
old_file = open_workbook(each_file,formatting_info=True)
old_sheet = old_file.sheet_by_index(0)

new_file = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8', style_compression = 0)
new_sheet = new_file.add_sheet('Sheet1', cell_overwrite_ok = True)

for row in range(10):
    for col in range(6):
        new_sheet.write(row,col,old_sheet.cell(row,col).value)
```

Comment: Would really like to know why this is a bad/wrong answer? Someone here who hates loops?

Comment: thanks for your help. hope you don't mind I choose other other as it's ever more direct.